# How to validate Yii2 dynamic model

Tags: yii2

I was working on Yii2 and would like to dynamically validate the field, like validate if another field is not selected.

I found below code on Yii2 documentation:

```
['state', 'required', 'when' => function($model) {
    return $model->country == 'USA';
}]
```

But the thing is that I am using Yii2 dynamic model. How could I achieve the same thing shown above in dynamic model.

Comment: not clear how are you initializing the dynamic model you need to call `addRule` on the dynamic model like,  `$model->addRule(['field_name','string',['max'=>255]])` , and then call the validate `$model->validate()`, this will call the validation and show you the errors, you need to show the code. you are working on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As usual model:

```
$model = new \yii\base\DynamicModel([
    'name', 'country', 'state'
]);

$model->addRule(
    'state', 'required', ['when' => function($model) {
        return $model->country == 'USA';
    }
]);
```

Comment: Your parameters in `addRule` are incorrect. `addRule` requires at least 2 arguments. Should be `->addRule('state', 'required', ['when'...]);`. See https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-dynamicmodel#addRule()-detail